# why does my vlookup vba code shows an error of 400

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have the same code in the same workbook and in a separate sheet and it was working perfectly alright. I copied the same code for the same workbook but different sheet and there goes an error.

```
Sub ExecuteLkup()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="V:\Mar22\Top Segments & Top All_Mar22.xlsx")
Set ws = Sheet4

Range("K2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("F").Value, wb.Sheets("TopAll").Range("E:I"), 5, 0)
        


With ws
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

.Cells(1, LastCol + 1).Value = "Variance"

End With
  
   Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[BRN_nett_grand_total]]-[@Column1]"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your range("K2") and range("L2") don't have a wb/ws specified. What's the error and what line does it trigger?

Comment: Put your code in a general module and then refactor it so that it takes a worksheet as an input parameter.  All calls to worksheetmethods must be qualified by reference to the worksheet passed in a a parameter.

Comment: I have some doubts that the code previously worked using `Range("F").Value`... Now, naturally activating `wb` after opening, `Range("K2")` refers the active sheet of `wb` workbook, and it should work if `Lookup_value` is correct. It may return even an array for more cells in its range, but in such a case it cannot return in a single cell. A better idea is to use a `Variant` variable and `Application.VLookup` which does not return a fatal error in case of no any match. Something as `Dim VLKarr` `VLKarr = Application.Vlookup(Range("F2").Value, wb.Sheets("TopAll").Range("E:I"), 5, 0)`.

Comment: Followed by  'If not IsError(VLKarr) Then` do whatever. Now it will not return a (fatal) error even if no match has been found...

Comment: @OwlSleeping, it triggers at this line: 
Range("K2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("F").Value, wb.Sheets("TopAll").Range("E:I"), 5, 0) showing an error of 400

I try to insert and amend the following code:

Dim ws As Worksheet

Worksheets("TopAll").Range("K2").Value = WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("F").Value, wb.Sheets("TopAll").Range("E:I"), 5, 0)

still it doesn't work

Comment: Please, try a simple debugging line: `Debug.print Range("F").Value`. What does it return in Immediate Window? Did you try understanding what I commented above?

Comment: i tried adding the following:

'Dim VL as variant
VL = Application.Vlookup(Range("F2").Value, wb.Sheets("TopAll").Range("E:I"), 5, 0)"

the lookup function was not executed

Comment: Did you adapt `Range("F2").Value` according to your need? I place there a working range, of course, not knowing what range you want using. To replace `Range("F").Value`, which is a strange construction.

Comment: yup  done that as well. didn't work. tried to transfer the vba code to a module, also didn't work either.